# Why can't I push onto stack? Java 6 generics

Tags: java, generics, nullpointerexception, stack

I have no idea why I'm unable to do something as simple as push a generic type of object onto a stack. I've decided I need some help figuring this out. This is what I have:

```
private void preOrderTrav(BSTnode<K> node) {
            if(node != null){
            myStack.push(node); //Null pointer exception

            while(!myStack.isEmpty()){
                myStack.pop();
                node = node.getLeft();
                myStack.push(node.getRight());
                myStack.push(node.getLeft());

                }

            }
               }
```

This is being called from my constructor:

```
public BSTSortedListIterator(BSTnode<K> root) {
    preOrderTrav(root);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? I get this error, by the way:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BSTSortedListIterator.preOrderTrav(BSTSortedListIterator.java:33)
    at BSTSortedListIterator.preOrderTrav(BSTSortedListIterator.java:31)
    at BSTSortedListIterator.<init>(BSTSortedListIterator.java:43)
    at BSTSortedList.iterator(BSTSortedList.java:130)
    at WebDictionary.main(WebDictionary.java:135)
```

Comment: Have you initialized myStack? From the code you have posted its not clear.

Comment: Seems like you `myStack` instance could be null

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure this is where you are getting NullPointerException

```
myStack.push(node);
```

and as you have mentioned that there is a check

```
if(node != null)
```

only thing that can be null is **myStack**. Or else this is incomplete information.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BSTSortedListIterator.preOrderTrav(BSTSortedListIterator.java:33)
```

Is this  `myStack.push(node);` line number 33 in BSTSortedListIterator.java

Answer (score 1):

In most probability `myStack` instance is null as `stack.push` would not throw error even in case of null element being inserted. `Java` `Stack` classes uses `Vector` (or array specifically) as underlying storage which on adding element add elements into its array:

```
elementData[elementCount++] = obj;
```

So, I don't see on that line NPE is due push method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the myStack object in your main or elsewhere, but before any call to preOrderTrav(node). If there is no line anywhere like

```
myStack = new Stack<K>()
```

then chances are, that you forgot about this.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, I used `JAVA 8`.

At the beginning, I set my variable to `static Stack<Node> stack;`

Then I got `null pointer`.

I solve this by setting the variable like:

```
static Stack<Node> stack= new Stack<Node>();
```